# check response value json is valid or not in salesforce lightning component controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to check whether a response.getReturnValue() is valid JSON or not .if it is a valid JSON then it should parse otherwise it shows error

```
if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                   console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                    var jsonData=JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                    console.log(jsonData); 
                    if(!jsonData){
                    component.set("v.Servererror",'Null');
                    }else(jsonData['Client']!=null){
                      component.set("v.Servererror",jsonData['Client']);
                    }
             }
```

How to check whether it is a valid JSON or not ?

Comment: You will always get a valid JSON from the server no need to send JSON string from Apex and parse that in the JS controller.

Comment: Are you returning a manually-constructed JSON string from Apex? There should never be a need to validate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this line:

```
var jsonData=JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
```

JSON.parse would throw an exception if it were invalid JSON. You can wrap this in a try-catch block:

```
try {
  var jsonData=JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
  component.set("v.Servererror",jsonData.Client);
} catch(e) {
  component.set("v.Servererror",null);
}
```